# Can anyone explain Monads?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, glossary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad)

I think I understand what 'Maybe Monads' are, but I'm not sure about the other types.