# Haskell monad: etymology versus meaning?

Tags: haskell, terminology, monads

When I'm developing an understanding of some concept, I find it very unsatisfactory not to be able to see how the apparent etymology of the concept name relates to what I think I'm understanding about the concept.  If I can't see the connection, I'm left with the feeling that there's some significant insight the name is trying to convey that I haven't yet discovered.

Monad: From Greek for unity. Mon = one; ad = a group or unit comprising a certain number. This composes to "A group or unit composed of one thing".

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/All_About_Monads says:

"A monad is a way to structure computations in terms of values and sequences of computations using those values. Monads allow the programmer to build up computations using sequential building blocks, which can themselves be sequences of computations." ... "Other monads exist for building computations that perform I/O, have state, may return multiple results, etc"

Nothing much there about one-ness.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad claims that the one-ness in term monad refers to the *one* output that a monad will produce.  But given that *any* function produces one output, (and the above reference says "may return multiple results", not to mention out-of-band/error results), and there's nothing about the "group or unit", that explanation seems unconvincing.

Is there some better explanation?

[Edit: Responding to the "off topic" flag.  My question is not about the etymology of the word "monad" per se.  It is about the Haskell concept of monad, and how the roots of the word monad do or do not inform us about that concept, or perhaps actually misdirect us from understanding the topic. Given that monad is a famously hard-to-communicate concept in Haskell, this is certainly a question about programming.

That this is a salient issue is reinforced by the variation in respondent suggestions regarding how the roots in "monad" might relate to the topic at hand, including the observation that the explanation in Haskell's own documentation is highly suspect.

That said, I'm pretty satisfied with the answers given (thanks all!), so no need to reopen the topic. But I'd advocate not moving it elsewhere, so that others with the same confusion *about an important Haskell concept* can find it here.]

Comment: Haskell monad is named so after the category theory monad. So you should be asking about the etymology of that. But then I doubt this question belongs to SO.

Comment: Monad is a word-play on "monoid" (a mathematical concept, of which monad is a generalization) and "triple" (the old term for monad, called so because it comes in three parts).

Comment: @Roman Thanks for your comment, and yes I was aware that the term comes from abstract algebra. That said, etymology includes the study of the *changes* of meaning, and in the current question, how the constituent roots might relate to the programming concept of monads, the better to understand the nature and intent of Haskell monads. (I'm spelling this out here in the hopes that this question doesn't suffer the fate of the great answer developed by C A McCann, referenced below).

Comment: The fact that a Haskell monad is both a group of computations and a single computation simultaneously is perfectly in line with the definition given.

Comment: This is actually an interesting question.  The Haskell monad comes from the category theory monad, which comes from Leibnitz's monadology, which ultimately draws upon Platonic and Egyptian realism. A monad is a "completed totality" made up of adjoint functors.  In such a way, it is a generalization of a closure operator.  Etc.

Comment: @n.m.: no it isn't.  The word comes from Leibnitz's monadology, specifically because the role it plays in topos theory (interpreters for algebras of logical expressions) is the same role they did for Leibnitz.

Comment: @nomen The two interpretations are by no means mutually exclusive.

Comment: @nomen [Related discussion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30654/where-does-the-term-monad-come-from).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there some better explanation?

Short answer: No, there really isn't.

Slightly less short answer: It's almost certainly related to "monoid", and not related to any other use of "monad" (there are at least two), and the term was coined at a gathering of mathematicians so there's likely not even a written source that's the first use of the term.

Longer answer with quotes and citations: [The one I wrote here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/30661/10124)

That claim on the wiki about the alleged meaning seems very dubious to me, incidentally.

Comment: +1. But it's a pity that the questions was migrated to *english* from *programmers*

Comment: @Raffaele: It's a question about etymology, having nothing to do with programming as such. Where else would it go? Math.SE?

Comment: I don't think *english* has the audience of stackoverflow, neither quantitatively (and so this is a pity because yours is a very well-written answer) nor qualitatively (in the sense of the interests of the users). *math* would be the most in-topic place, except that likely mathemeticians already know the concept, whereas it sounds completely new to developers approaching functional programming, and they can't know where to look for. So I think it should belong to stackoverflow because, even if slightly offtopic, there's the greatest number of users who can benefit from it. Just my opinion, btw

Comment: Hahaha I'm feeling surprisingly satisfied by such an authoritatively unsatisfying answer :-). So what I'm getting is: the algebra term "monad" derives via "having some qualities of a monoid", but the characteristics of interest of a monad in Haskell have little or nothing to do with its being like a (Haskell) monoid. In particular, the one-ness that really does relate to monoids ("oneness" suggests the identity value and operation) has no prominent salience to the Haskell monad.

Comment: @Raffaele:  Yes, it does seem odd that CA's great answer is sidelined over in "english". I agree that the term is unlikely to mystify mathematicians, wouldn't be sought by ordinary mortals, and is most puzzling to software folks. But maybe the current post will enable programmers to find it.

Comment: @gwideman: The closest equivalent `Monoid` instance would be `Endo a`, the monoid of endomorphisms `a -> a` and function composition, where the identity value is (of course) `id`. `Monad` is a monoid of *endofunctors* on the category of Haskell types, with *functor* composition as the operation and the identity functor as the identity value. For a monad `m`, we can get `m a` from `Id a`--that is, just `a`--using `return`, and from `m` composed with itself `m (m a)` we can get just `m a` using `join`. The monoid structure is still very relevant, it's just at a different level.

Comment: @Raffaele: Incidentally, I did a quick search on math.SE and found at least a half-dozen questions of the form "what is the origin of the term X", of which many were upvoted and none were closed. This really is mostly off-topic for SO, but if you want, you can flag for moderator attention and request it be moved to math.SE, since it looks like it might be welcome there.