# What is the difference between monads and macros?

Tags: haskell, macros, functional-programming, scheme, monads

I've read some monads tutoriais and they pretty much propose that monads are necessary to implement sequencing of operations. But the same can be accomplished with `let`:

```
(let*
    (   (a 1)
        (b (+ a 1))
        (c (+ b 1)))
    c)
```

Is desucared to (not actually, I wrote this braindead for illustration purposes, see Will Ness's comment):

```
((lambda (c) c)
    ((lambda (b) (+ b 1)) 
        ((lambda (a) (+ a 1))
            1)))
```

So how come monads be necessary to implement sequencing, if this macro can do it already?

Comment: Macros are more analogous to lazy evaluation. Macros could be used to implement syntactic sugar for a monadic interface, but a monad is just a set of laws on a type (which you can see here http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad . There are also many different monads. Additionally, I don't think what you're describing is really a monad, but is instead just normal identifier binding.

Comment: Macros are AST transformators. You can work on ASTs with `TemplateHaskell`, but they don't really have any relation to monads.

Comment: The only reason your macro sequences anything is because the arguments to a procedure get evaluated before evaluating an application. I'm confused by your example because you talk about sequencing which is really only relevant if w're talking about side-effects, which your code has none of. And even if you did use lambdas to try sequencing things, it would be bad practice to do so since it assumes something about how evaluation is implemented. In Scheme you would use the `begin` form for that.

Comment: The sequencing `let` is usually known as `let*`, not `letrec`, and it allows us to write e.g. `(let*
( (a 1) (b (+ a 1)) (c (+ b a))) c)`

The desugaring scheme that you propose is very unusual, and it won't work because there's no nesting of scope, i.e. no shared access to same variables: ``((lambda (c) c) ((lambda (b) (+ b a))     #| doesn't work: what `a`? |#
 ((lambda (a) (+ a 1)) 1)))``

The usual translation for `let*` is

`((lambda (a) ((lambda (b) ((lambda (c) c)  (+ b a))  (+ a 1))  1)` where the scopes of each var are nested, so the inner expression has access to outer vars.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A monad is just a set of laws defined on a type. Here are what the laws would look like in Scheme notation (`return` and `>>=` are the monadic functions):

```lisp
(>>= (return a) k)                 ==  (k a)            ; Left identity
(>>= m return)                     ==  m                ; Right identity
(>>= m (lambda (x) (>>= (k x) h))) == (>>= (>>= m k) h) ; Associativity
```

Translating this gets tricky though because Scheme is dynamically typed. `>>=` and `return` have different behavior depending on the types involved.

A simple example is the `Maybe` monad, which could look something like this in Scheme:

```lisp
(define (Just x)
    (cons 'Just x))
(define Nothing 'Nothing)

(define return Just)
(define (>>= m f)
   (if (eq? m 'Nothing)
       'Nothing
       (f (cdr m))))
```

This can be considered to represent a computation that might fail. Here are some examples of the Maybe monad:

```lisp
(>>= (Just 1) (lambda (x) (return (+ x 5))))   ==  '(Just . 6)
(>>= Nothing  (lambda (x) (return (* x 10))))  ==  'Nothing
(>>= (Just 5) (lambda (x) Nothing))            ==  'Nothing
```

Note how if any of the subcomputations result in `Nothing`, the entire computation results in Nothing. This is the major feature of the `Maybe` monad.

Another common example is the list monad, which could look something like

```lisp
(define (return x) (list x))
(define (>>= xs f)
    (flatten (map f xs)))
```

This monad can be thought of as a nondeterministic computation (that is, a computation that might have take on several possible values). Here are some examples:

```lisp
(>>= '(1 2 3) (lambda (x) (return (* x 10))))        == '(10 20 30)
(>>= '(5 6 7) (lambda (x) (list (* x 10) (+ x 2))))  == '(50 7 60 8 70 9)
```

***Note***:
I would highly recommend learning about functors (in the sense that the word is used in Haskell) and applicative functors before really trying to learn monads. These concepts build on each other.

Answer (score 5):

(Edited for clarity to more directly address the question.)

### Monads and Macros

Monads and macros are different sorts of things. As I'll show below, monad `do`
notation for the `Identity` monad in Haskell is similar to `let-rec` in the
desugaring. Then we'll see how the desugaring is not equivalent due to lazy 
evaluation in Haskell.

The summary, if you don't care to read any further, is that a macro rewrites
the syntax tree (in Lisps), and in Haskell, monad `do`-notation is syntax
sugar. Monads themselves are just types that have an associated dictionary of
functions, so the `Identity` monad is not the same as `IO`, which is not the
same as `STM` or `Either` or `Cont`.

### Does Monad-Do Sequence Expressions?

First, let's assume Lisps and Haskell have the same execution strategy (strict,
call by value). In this assumption, there is not much difference between
Haskell's  `Monad` `do`-notation and the average Lisp's `let-rec`. For all of
the Haskell I'm going to be showing, I'm going to have this import statement at
the top:

```
import Control.Monad.Identity
```

So, consider the following function:

```
f :: Identity Int 
f = do
  a <- return 1
  b <- return (a + 1)
  c <- return (b + 1)
  return c
```

I am using the Identity monad, which behaves the most similarly to `let-rec`.
The `do` notation will desugar to this:

```
fDesugar :: Identity Int
fDesugar =
  (return 1 >>= \a -> 
    (return (a + 1) >>= \b ->
      (return (b + 1) >>= \c ->
        return c)))
```

This looks like your Lisp example, but obviously it is using infix notation and
this results in a different sequence of arguments. We can rewrite it to be Lisp
like:

```
fLisp :: Identity Int
fLisp =
  ((=<<) (\c -> return c)
    ((=<<) (\b -> return (b + 1))
      ((=<<) (\a -> return (a + 1))
        (return 1))))
```

Now, we can "run" this monad using `runIdentity`. What does that mean? Why do we
need to "run" monads?

### Using Monads

Monads are defined on constructors of types. Some tutorials describe them as
burrito wrappers, but I'm just going to say that a monad can be defined on a lot
of types-that-take-types. One example of a monad is the one I've already used,
`Identity`, another monad is `IO`. Each of these types is actually a value of
kind `* -> *`, that is, it takes a type (of kind `*`) and returns a new type. So
a monad is defined for `Identity`, which can then be used with `Identity Int`,
`Identity String`, `Identity Foo`, and so on.

Because monads are defined *per-type*, when evaluating something of type
`Identity T`, we need to know how to execute that monad. The sequencing, so to
speak, is dependent on the types.

Identity is a very simple constructor and monad. The constructor is:

```
newtype Identity a = Identity { runIdentity :: a }
```

That is, to construct a value of type `Identity T`, we just need to pass in a 
`T`. And to get it out, we just apply `runIdentity` to it. That is:

```
makeIdentity :: a -> Identity a
makeIdentity a = Identity a

runIdentity :: Identity a -> a
runIdentity (Identity a) = a
```

To understand `fLisp`, `fDesugar`, or `f`, we need to know what `>>=` and
`return` mean in the context of the `Identity` monad:

```
instance Monad Identity where
    return a = Identity a
    m >>= k  = k (runIdentity m)
```

With this knowledge, we can derive `=<<` for Identity:

```
    k =<< m = k (runIdentity m)
```

With this in hand, we can rewrite `fLisp`, using our definitions. In Haskell 
parlance, we are using equational reasoning. We can substitute the left hand 
side of our definitions above with the right hand side. So we substitute
`(=<<) a b` with `a (runIdentity b)`, and `return a` with `Identity a`:

```
fLisp' :: Identity Int
fLisp' =
  ((\c -> Identity c)
    (runIdentity ((\b -> Identity (b + 1))
      (runIdentity ((\a -> Identity (a + 1))
        (runIdentity (Identity 1)))))))
```

But `runIdentity` just strips `Identity` from whatever it is applied to. When
 `runIdentity` is applied to something of the form:
 `runIdentity ((\a -> Identity (f a)) b)` we can move it inside its argument:
 `(\a -> runIdentity (Identity a)) b`, and reduce it to `(\a -> f a) b` or just
 `f a`. Let's do all those steps:

```
fLisp'' :: Identity Int
fLisp'' =
  ((\c -> Identity c)
    (((\b -> (b + 1))
      (((\a -> (a + 1))
        1)))))
```

We can finally take the last `Identity` out of the first function, and we get:

```
fLisp''' :: Identity Int
fLisp''' =
  Identity 
    ((\c -> c)
      (((\b -> (b + 1))
        (((\a -> (a + 1))
          1)))))
```

So, clearly `Identity` behaves identically to `let-rec`, right?

### Where Monads Differ

Monads are defined per-type, so `Identity` is a lot like your macro `let-rec`, 
but where the two differ in a critical way is that Haskell *does not* behave as
we assumed. Haskell does not perform strict, call-by-value evaluation.

We can prove this by writing this in Haskell. `blowUp` is a raw error type, when
evaluated it will bubble up an exception and end execution.

```
blowUp :: a
blowUp = error "I will crash Haskell!"

riskyPair :: (Int, a) 
riskyPair = (5, blowUp)

fst' :: (a, b) -> a
fst' = \(a, b) -> a

five :: Int
five = fst' riskyPair
```

When `five` is evaluated, the result is indeed five. Despite it coming from the
tainted value `g`, we are able to safely evaluate `fst' riskyPair` without 
blowing up. Try evaluating `riskyPair` though, and you'll see the exception.

Consider the following function `g`, it uses the Identity monad, but what does
it do?

```
g :: Identity Int
g = do
  a <- return 1
  b <- return (a + 1)
  c <- return (b + 1)
  d <- return (blowUp)
  return c
```

Curiously, `runIdentity g` returns `3`. The same as `runIdentity f`.

Monads are not macros, not even the `Identity` monad duplicates the behavior of
`let-rec`. I tried this in Racket, and I got an error. I could not even compile
the program! Defining `g` evaluated the error code.

```
(define g 
    (letrec
      (   (a 1)
          (b (+ a 1))
          (c (+ b 1))
          (d (error "I will crash Racket!"))
    ) c))
```

### Why Do Monads Differ?

In Haskell, values are lazy in their arguments. If the second value of the pair
is never forced (required) then Haskell will not blow up. And `fst f` is "safe"
to execute. In Lisp, values are strict, and `g` will always blow up.

Because of Haskell's laziness, many authors will hand-wave monads as the only
way of sequencing operations. This is not strictly true! (No pun intended.)

Monads, then, are not just macros for `let-rec`, because the definitions for
`>>=` and `return` can vary so wildly. We can represent potentially failing
computations with the `Either` monad.

I tend to think of monads not as ways of sequencing operations, but more like a
user-defined "semicolon" operator. In some monads (`IO`), the act of binding is
a lot like a semi-colon in C or C++. In other monads, the semicolons (binds) do
other things, like chain together error conditions or modify control flow.

See [this example](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.0.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Cont.html#g:5)
of the `Cont` monad for reference. Notice that in this case, inside the `Cont`
monad, the flow of execution can be altered by statements inside the `do` block.

Comment: I came across [this great description about a monads](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10245311/2388257), and it seems to me that monads is an abstract idea, but a macros is an implementation. So it is a fail idea to compare monads and macros, it is completely different things. I.e. it seems to me that the macros is just a way of implementing monads in C language.

Answer (score 5):

A Monad is not a macro. A Monad is the existence of two functions with a particular correspondence between them. So it does not do away with the lambdas, but specifies a restriction upon them.

I wouldn't say that monads "sequence" operations. It is not always what they do. A `(r->a)` is a monad in `a`, and it certainly does not "sequence" anything. A `((a->r)->a)` is a Monad in `a`, too.

I suggest the focus of understanding the monads should really be on understanding the meaning of those two operations and the laws. Usually the tutorials talk about `return` and `>>=`, but the epiphany is in understanding `<=<`, which can be used to express `>>=`.

In "plain" types you define composition as:

```
(.) :: (b->c) -> (a->b) -> (a->c)
```

then write

```
f . g
```

Using monads, you define composition as:

```
(<=<) :: (Monad m) => (b->m c) -> (a->m b) -> (a->m c)
```

then write

```
f <=< g
```

Comment: @WillNess Thanks. Added clarification. It is the search monad.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s worth adding a subtle point here.

The monad design pattern and macros offer similar results, which, I think led to this question.

Monads offer a way to extract repeated code and the ability to branch off based on some condition in most FP languages besides providing alternate ways to sequence two functions by wrapping some underlying type with a context that we can control.

However, in lisps we don’t need it because macros are much more powerful and provide same or more functionality. We can rearrange code however we like. Thus we use the threading macros, the cond macro, the let macro etc in Clojure.

Thus, as we can see, monads, lawful or unlawful are very useful in languages with limited code manipulation support but if you’re using something lispy macros often much more useful.