# Implement mapM without using sequence

Tags: haskell, monads

I am currently trying to solve the [20 Intermediate Haskell Excercises](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/20-intermediate-haskell-exercises/) excercises and am stuck which trying to implement `mapM` (which is `moppy` in the excercise) without the use of `sequence`.

All I can produce is a `[m b]` by simply applying `fmap` but I don't know how to continue:

```
moppy :: [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
moppy la f = furry' f la -- how do I transform [m b] to m [b] without sequence
```

Can someone give me a hint in which direction to look?

Comment: In general if you ever want to add more "context" than `map` will allow you, consider using either a fold or explicit recursion to traverse your data structure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the modern era, as Benjamin Hodgson mentioned, we should be using `Applicative` for this particular purpose:

```
myMapM :: Applicative f
       => (a -> f b) -> [a] -> f [b]
```

We want `myMapM f []` to be `pure []` (there's no way we can get any `b`s!), so

```
myMapM f [] = pure []
```

Now we get to the heart of the matter, figuring out the recursive step. We want `myMapM f (x : xs)` to perform `f x`, perform `myMapM f xs`, and combine the results. So

```
myMapM f [] = pure []
myMapM f (x : xs) = (:) <$> f x <*> myMapM f xs
```

When doing something nice and regular with a list, we can very often get away with just `foldr`:

```
myMapM f = foldr go (pure []) where
  go x r = (:) <$> f x <*> r
```

Comment: For true inscrutability, ``myMapM = (`foldr` pure []) . (((<*>) . fmap (:)) .)``

Comment: i.e. `liftA2 (:) . f` in the `foldr`, to get a one-liner, and to avoid the scare brackets. :)

Answer (score 3):

Well I don't know how to do this without too much spoiler -- so here you go with a very basic / recursive definition:

```
moppy :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
moppy [] _ = return []
moppy (x:xs) f = do
  y  <- f x
  ys <- moppy xs f
  return (y:ys)
```

It should be rather self-explanatory -- please note that you need the `Monad m` constraint (I think you want it anyway, as it gets rather impossible without it ;) )

Comment: You only need `Applicative m` to write `mapM` (aka `traverse`). `traverse f (x:xs) = (:) <$> f x <*> traverse f xs`

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson told you it's *basic* - IMO it's a bit problematic to tell someone about `Traversable` if they struggle with monads (and I think most can handle `do` notations as they look familiar-imperative) - but why don't you add this as a nice answer?

Comment: we could have Monadic do... Applicative do... Functorial do! or in the other direction, [LiftF... LiftA2... liftBind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53829742/849891). and yes, I think `do` notation could be the gateway drug to monads, and should even be presented much earlier than `>>=` or even the name "monad" is mentioned. Come to think of it, teaching Haskell should start with `main = do { putStrLn "Hello, World!"; return () }`!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it helps when you start with implementing `mapM` with just `>>=` and `return`. You would end up with something similar to:

```
mapM' :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
mapM' _ []     = return []
mapM' f (x:xs) =        f x           >>=
                 \y  -> mapM' f xs    >>=
                 \ys -> return (y:ys)
```

This kind of gives you the answer as the previous poster mentioned. All you need to do is change the order of arguments:

```
moppy :: (Misty m) => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]      
moppy []     _ = unicorn []
moppy (x:xs) f = banana (\y -> banana (\ys -> unicorn (y:ys)) (moppy xs f)) (f x)
```

Or:

```
moppy :: (Misty m) => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]      
moppy []     _ = unicorn []
moppy (x:xs) f = (\y  -> (\ys -> unicorn (y:ys)) `banana` moppy xs f) `banana` f x
```

Or:

```
moppy :: (Misty m) => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]      
moppy []     _ = unicorn []
moppy (x:xs) f = let g y = let h ys = unicorn (y : ys)
                            in h `banana` moppy xs f
                  in g `banana` f x
```

Answer (score 1):

Take this implementation:

```
moppy :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
moppy f xs = foldr g n xs 
  where
    n = return []
    g x mys = do {
      y  <- f x ;
      ys <- mys ;
      return (y:ys) }
```

(`mys :: m [b]` because `foldr g n (x:xs) = g x (foldr g n xs)`.)

(adapted from C9 Lectures: Ralf Lämmel - Going Bananas [8:06 min - youtube).