# Is the implementation of `<*>` based on `fmap` special to Maybe applicative or can it be generalized to other applicatives?

Tags: haskell, applicative, option-type

In Maybe applicative, `<*>` can be implemented based on `fmap`. Is it incidental, or can it be generalized to other applicative(s)?

```
(<*>)   ::  Maybe   (a  ->  b)  ->  Maybe   a   ->  Maybe   b
Nothing <*> _   =   Nothing
(Just   g)  <*> mx  =   fmap    g   mx
```

Thanks.

See also [In applicative, how can `<*>` be represented in terms of `fmap_i, i=0,1,2,...`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188385/in-applicative-how-can-be-represented-in-terms-of-fmap-i-i-0-1-2)

Comment: Since the `fmap f x = pure f <*> x` law holds, it is not uncommon that one is sometimes implemented in terms of the other. But here the implementation of `<*>` still does some work: it does pattern matching and unwraps the `g` out of the `Just` data constructor.

Comment: Note that your `fmap0` is `pure`, something that is *not* defined on a `Functor`.

Comment: Thanks. In Maybe applicative, could you write `<*> without fmap?

Comment: you can just "inline" the definition of `fmap` in the definition of `(<*>)`, like `Just f <*> Just x = Just (f x)` and `_ <*> _ = Nothing`

Comment: As @AJFarmar already says, it might probably help to "get your hands dirty" and do some implementations. Yes studying algebraic structures definitely has a lot of value (especially in Haskell), but usually one appreciates the power of algebraic structures more, once one has solved some challenges.

Answer (score 5):

It cannot be generalized. A `Functor` instance is unique:

```
instance Functor [] where
    fmap = map
```

but there can be multiple valid `Applicative` instances for the same type constructor.

```
-- "Canonical" instance: [f, g] <*> [x, y] == [f x, f y, g x, g y]
instance Applicative [] where
    pure x = [x]
    [] <*> _ = []
    (f:fs) <*> xs = fmap f xs ++ (fs <*> xs)

-- Zip instance: [f, g] <*> [x, y] == [f x, g y]
instance Applicative [] where
    pure x = repeat x
    (f:fs) <*> (x:xs) = f x : (fs <*> xs)
    _ <*> _ = []
```

In the latter, we neither want to apply any single function from the left argument to all elements of the right, nor apply all the functions on the left to any single element on the right, making `fmap` useless.

Comment: Yeah, blanked on `concat`'s arguments (would have been `concat [fmap f xs, fs <*> xs]`).

Comment: `(f:fs) <*> xs = fmap f xs ++ (fs <*> xs) = concat [fmap f xs, fs <*> xs] = concat [fmap f xs | f <- fs] = [f x | f <- fx, x <- xs]` ... (it also means, `[f, g] <*> [x, y] == [f x, f y, g x, g y]` ...) BTW it's interesting, could the transposed version be the canonical...? probably would break some laws maybe...

Comment: @WillNess That's actually the equivalence I meant to add in the comment. On the plus side, I think this answer is running out of things to fix :)