# What does >>= mean in purescript?

Tags: purescript

I was reading the [purescript wiki](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/Language-Guide) and found following section which explains `do` in terms of `>>=`.

What does `>>=` mean?

> **Do notation**
>
> The do keyword introduces simple syntactic sugar for monadic
>   expressions.
>
> Here is an example, using the monad for the `Maybe` type:
>
> ```
>  maybeSum :: Maybe Number -> Maybe Number -> Maybe Number 
>  maybeSum a b = do   
>      n <- a
>      m <- b   
>      let result = n + m   
>      return result
> ```
>
> `maybeSum` takes two
>   values of type `Maybe Number` and returns their sum if neither number is
>   `Nothing`.
>
> When using do notation, there must be a corresponding
>   instance of the Monad type class for the return type. Statements can
>   have the following form:
>
> - `a <- x` which desugars to `x >>= \a -> ...`
> - `x` which desugars to `x >>= \_ -> ...` or just x if this is the last statement.
> - A let binding `let a = x`. Note the lack of the `in` keyword.
>
> The example `maybeSum desugars to` ::
>
> ```
>  maybeSum a b =
>    a >>= \n ->
>      b >>= \m ->
>        let result = n + m
>        in return result
> ```

Comment: > The do keyword introduces simple syntactic sugar for monadic expressions. 6 years later and this sentence still makes no sense at all

Comment: @CodeWhisperer .. "syntactic sugar" is just 'a nicer way to write the same thing.
A monadic expression is an expression using modads. in this case the Maybe monad. 
Monads are types that wrap other types in order to  make code composable/chainable 
Typically you wrap your base type... do your operations to the wrapped type,.. then unwrap the result to see what you got.  The maybe monad handles null propergation.
In this case `do` lets you skip some indentation  making the code look more precedural

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`>>=` is a function, nothing more. It resides in the Prelude module and has type `(>>=) :: forall m a b. (Bind m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, being an alias for the `bind` function of the `Bind` type class. You can find the definitions of the Prelude module in [this link](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/0.1.3/docs/Prelude), found in the [Pursuit package index](https://pursuit.purescript.org).

This is closely related to the `Monad` type class in Haskell, which is a bit easier to find resources. There's a [famous question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad) about this concept, which is a good starting point if you're looking to improve your knowledge on the bind function (if you're starting on functional programming now, you can skip it for a while).