# What >> operator does?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm learning about monad in Haskell.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad) an excelent explaination about Monads, and I think to have understand (not all, but ehy I just started) about `>>=` bind operator and Monad.

On my teacher's slides I found this:

```
class  Monad m  where
    (>>=)            :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b   -- "bind"
    (>>)             :: m a -> m b -> m b          -- "then"
    return           :: a -> m a
```

What is `>>` and in what it differs from `>>=`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`>>` is a shortcut for when you don't care about the value. That is, `a >> b` is equivalent to `a >>= \_ -> b` (assuming a sane (or default) definition of `>>` in the given monad).

So when you're, say, in the IO monad and want to execute some `print`s, you can use `>>` because there's no reason to do anything with the `()` that `print` produces: `print a >> print b`.

In terms of do-notation `exp >>= \var -> rest` corresponds to

```
do
  var <- exp
  rest
```

and `exp >> rest` corresponds to just

```
do
  exp
  rest
```

Comment: The doubt comes from "then" I was thinking it was an implication or something similar. Thank's for your answer.

Comment: @granmirupa The "then" is meant in the sense of "do x, then do y".

Answer (score 6):

`>>` performs the monadic action on the left hand side but discards its result and then performs the right hand side.

when you are using do - notation this is what happens when you write something like

```
... = do _ <- action1
         action2
```

or shorter (but the compiler will issue a warning of unbound `action1`)

```
... = do action1
         action2
```

now where is that useful - consider the situation of a monadic parser where you

```
... = do string "IP:"
         d1 <- decimal
         char '.'
         d2 <- decimal
         char '.'
         d3 <- decimal
         char '.'
         d4 <- decimal
         char '.'
         return $ IP d1 d2 d3 d4
```

here you are interested in the actual numbers but not in the dots in between or the string "IP:" at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The `>>` operator works as the `>>=` operator and is used when the function does not need the value produced by the first monadic operator.

To better understand it a comparation with `do` notation is useful:

> The (>>) (then) operator works almost identically in do notation and
>   in unsugared code. 
>    [[here]](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation)

You can look better at this example:

```
putStr "Hello" >> 
putStr " " >> 
putStr "world!" >> 
putStr "\n"
```

that is equivalent to:

```
do putStr "Hello"
   putStr " "
   putStr "world!"
   putStr "\n"
```