# What is the proper name for (>>) operator in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, terminology

The monadic `(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b` operator is well-known. I wonder what its name is.

- In [this Haskell tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Yet_Another_Haskell_Tutorial/Monads) and also in [this one](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) they call this operator a **"then"**. It is a nice name, it makes perfect sense in terms of the **`do`-notation**. A minor downside is the collision with **then** of the ternary operator.
- In my native *Haskell tradition* we call it a **"усечённое связывание"**, translation being **"truncated bind"**. It might be a little inconvenient in Russian as it sort of collides with the translation for **"bind's section"**, but I do not see any similar issue in English. Does anyone use such a name or some similar one in English? A poetic way to put this would probably be a [**"frustum"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum).

Does anyone use any other name for the operator? What is the preferred one?

Comment: Everyone calls it `then`, yes: https://wiki.haskell.org/Pronunciation, https://stackoverflow.com/q/37136294/1048572, https://stackoverflow.com/q/7746894/1048572

Comment: I read it as "and then", to disambiguate.

Comment: "Sequence" is the name "then" is the pronunciation when reading code.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson to be frank, I like "sequence" the least as there is another function called ["sequence"](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequence), which appears in monadic code frequently. Unlike others, this collision seems to be major.

Comment: The key is to distinguish it from `<*`, one way or another. I use "then" or "and then" for `>>` and `*>`, and "before" for `<*`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call it "short fish". (Because `>=>` is the "fish", and `>>` is that with a shorter body.)

Or maybe "fsh", a "fish" without the *i*nternal part.

Since I've seen the `(.).(.)` operator called by a certain name, I might also suggest calling `>>` by another name which you may discover by browsing this post's editing history...

Another possibility is... the *[chicane](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mLtwWverocs/maxresdefault.jpg) operator*.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor, I've suggested an third possible name.

Comment: I like your way of thinking ;).

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow is a good place for inventing names.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor, I think I have the "definitive" answer.