# what is difference between monadic collection, monadic type and monadic operation?

Tags: scala, monads

I have been trying to understand the concept of monads in scala. There are different terminologies associated with monads. Monadic typeclasses,  monadic type, monadic operation, monadic collection etc.
So i have questions like Can a monadic collection support a non-monadic operation?
Is it possible to demystify the different terminologies  associated with  monads in scala?

Comment: Hundreds of researchers and bloggers and StackOverflow users have spent at least the last decade "demystifying" monads. It's not like there's not enough to read about it. Here is essentially the same question that got >1k upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad .  "Is it possible to demystify the different usages on monads?" is really not a good question that could be answered within a single stackoverflow answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i got a good answer below for the question i asked about monad terminologies in scala. i updated question details for more clarity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can a monadic collection support a non-monadic operation

A monadic collection must define two methods: `pure` and `bind`. It must, most importantly, obey the Monad laws of identity (right and left) and associativity.

Such a collection is `List[A]` in Scala, which has `pure` via it's apply method:

```
val l: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
```

And `flatMap` (`bind`):

```
val flat = l.flatMap(i => List(i))
```

### Laws:

#### Left Identity:

```
val f: Int => List[Int] = x => List(x + 1)

val x = 1
val left = List(x).flatMap(f)
val right = f(x)

left == right
```

#### Right Identity:

```
val y = List(1)
val left = y.flatMap(List(_))
val right = y

left == right
```

#### Assosiativity:

```
val f: Int => List[Int] = x => List(x + 1)
val g: Int => List[Int] = x => List(x + 2)

val list = List(1,2,3)
val left = list.flatMap(f).flatMap(g)
val right = list.flatMap(x => f(x).flatMap(g))

left == right
```

As you can see, `List[A]` also supports other operations which are not part of the Monad definition, such as `map` (which is given for free by the fact `List[A]` is a monad, and every monad is also a functor), `filter`, `foldLeft`, etc.

To answer your question: Yes, a collection with monadic properties can support more than just the operations defined by a monad.

More specifically, we can say that `List[A]` is a monadic collection which *implements* the `Monad[List]` typeclass and by that *is a* monadic type which has monadic operations.