# Could std::unique_ptr be considered a monad?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, monads

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around monads. Unfortunately, most articles on the topic use Haskell without properly explaining the notation. Yet, as I am mainly programming in C++, I would like understand monads without learning a new programming language...

From what I gathered on the web, a monad `M` is a type constructor for a type `T`, which provides at least the following operations:

- an actual way to construct the type `T`
- a converter for converting an arbitrary type to `T` (apparently called **return** in Haskell)
- a combinator for applying the value stored in `T` to a function `f` (apparently called **bind** in Haskell)

Applying these criteria to C++, it seems to me that `std::unique_ptr` could be considered a monad. Is this true?

---

My reasoning is as follows:

The `std::unique_ptr` template is used to construct the actual type `std::unique_ptr<T>`, thus:

- the type constructor is either `std::unique_ptr<T>{}` or `std::make_unique<T>()`
- the converter, again, would be the constructor or `std::make_unique` (with arguments...)
- the combinator would be either `std::bind(func, pointer.get())`, `std::bind(func, *pointer)` or an equivalent lambda

Do you agree, or does the call to `operator*()`/`.get()` for the combinator disqualify `std::unique_ptr` from being a monad?

---

I get, that using `std::unique_ptr` as a monad might not make sense because it carries owner semantic. I would just like to know, if it is one.

Comment: Some noodling here: https://thebytekitchen.com/2014/12/05/harder-to-c-monads-for-mortals-5-pointers/

Comment: and here: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/monads-in-c.  Apparently not.

Comment: Here's a question: what does it matter? C++ as a language and library has basically none of the supporting infrastructure to make monads a thing. That is, two C++ things which happen to fit the definition of a "monad" may not have any interfaces in common, nor will there be a simple way to write a function that could take either of them (or any "monadic" type). So it's not clear what it matters if a particular type just so happens to fit the definition of a word. It won't change what the type does or what you can do with it, because the support infrastructure for that word doesn't exist.

Comment: and here: https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/02/26/c17-i-see-a-monad-in-your-future/  Still no mention, although `std::unique_ptr` is mentioned in the context of a functor.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the links! I'm currently skimming through them... Very interesting!

Comment: @Eljay As I mentioned... I don't understand Haskell! I saw this article before, and it is mostly gibberish to me. The notation is just too weird...

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure, but there seem to be lots of people liking monads for some reason, and I would like to understand why, plus how they work... Maybe if not monads themselves, some parts of them might be useful when writing c++...

Comment: "I would just like to know, if [ `std::unique_ptr` ] is one [ a monad ]."  No, `std:unique_ptr` is not a monad.  Your definition of monad is egregiously incorrect.

Comment: @Eljay It's fairly simple to supply `auto unit(auto v){ return std::make_unique<T>(v); }` and `auto bind(auto ptr, auto f) { return ptr ? f(*ptr) : nullptr; }` and see that it's `Maybe` / `Option`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Applying these criteria to C++, it seems to me that `std::unique_ptr` could be considered a monad. Is this true?

Your definition is missing the monad laws, but we can see that there is appropriate formulation by which `std::unique_ptr` (plus it's `bind` and `return`/`unit`) obeys them.

Given

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> unit(T t) { return std::make_unique<T>(t); }

template <typename T, typename U, typename F = std::function<std::unique_ptr<U>(T)>>
std::unique_ptr<U> bind(std::unique_ptr<T> ptr, F f) { return ptr ? f(*ptr) : nullptr; }
```

and a notion of expression equivalence (`≡`), i.e. "these two expressions result in the same value"

We require

- Left identity: `bind(unit(a), f) ≡ f(a)`
- Right identity: `bind(m, unit) ≡ m`
- Associativity: `bind(bind(m, f), g) ≡ bind(m, [](auto x){
  return bind(f(x), g); })`

> I get, that using `std::unique_ptr` as a monad might not make sense because it carries owner semantic. I would just like to know, if it is one.

A monad is something that applies a semantic, like `unique_ptr`'s ownership, or `vector`s multiplicity, or `future`'s asynchronicity. There are lots of things in C++ that are monads, but (as @NicolBolas notes) there isn't much that operates on the monadic structure.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the `std::bind` is the same thing as a monadic bind, despite having the same name.

Your reasoning is on the right path though. `return` is trivial for most types. `bind` is a little trickier. Say you have a function `f` that that takes an `A` and returns a `std::unique_ptr<B>`. The `bind` would need to take a pointer to `f` and a `std::unique_ptr<A>` as arguments, and return a `std::unique_ptr<B>`. This function may not be already in the standard library, but it wouldn't be too difficult to write. It basically "unwraps" the `std:unique_ptr<A>` into an `A`, then calls `f` on it.

People get hung up on wanting one abstract `bind` that will work for any monad, like in Haskell's typeclass. That undoubtedly makes it easier to *use* monads, but it isn't a requirement to *identify* one conceptually.

I personally think the array monad is the easiest to grasp, because people are so familiar with it they may not even realize it's a monad. Say you have a function `f` that takes a string and returns an array of the characters in the string. Calling `bind(f, ["two", "strings"])` would return `['t', 'w', 'o', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 's']`. If you have a `g` that takes an integer `n` and returns an array from 1 to `n`, then you can use the exact same `bind` function to do `bind(g, [2, 0, 3])` with a result of `[1, 2, 1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Thanks, this is enlightening! I somewhere read about **bind** acting on a `std::function<std::unique_ptr<ResultT>(T)>`, but forgot about it... Do you know if there is a specific reason why `f` has to have this signature? Or could it also be `std::function<ResultT(T)>`, with **bind** wrapping the result into a `std::unique_ptr`? Plus, I like the array example. Would you mind expanding on it, for the benefit of other readers?

Comment: `f` having that signature is just how monads are defined. There's no reason you can't additionally support other signatures for `f` as you described, but without the one I described, it doesn't technically meet the definition.

Comment: Looking at @Caleths implementation of **bind**, the signature of `std::function<std::unique_ptr<ResultT>(T)>` makes sense now. `return ptr ? f(*ptr) : nullptr;` would not make sense (and wouldn't compile) if we had `std::function<ResultT(T)>`...

Comment: there is no one abstract bind that works for any monad in Haskell. Each Monad type defines its own; they are all just called "bind". It's just an overloaded function. Haskell's *typeclasses* were invented specifically so that Haskell could have function overloading, and Monad is a typeclass.

Comment: There is more than one way to create an abstraction. Overloading is one of them.

Comment: I merely commented on the Haskell's side of things. typeclasses were invented to have an "ad-hoc polymorphism", a Haskell jargon for function / operator / overloading. it is actually very confusing when monads are presented as some magic that works for every instance, when in fact each instance *defines* how it works, by definition. OTOH *after* the pattern is internalized, there's advantages to thinking in abstract terms of course.