# What is the type of <- in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, monads, io-monad, do-notation

I have a working program

```
main = do

  inpStr <- getLine
  putStrLn ( "Hello " ++ inpStr )
```

where

```
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

and

```
getLine :: IO String
```

From this can I conclude that the type of `<-` is

```
IO a -> a
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not a regular function, but a language construct. You can use it only in `do` blocks to "extract" value from some context, such as `IO`.

`do` blocks and `<-` is just a syntax sugar for such things called `Monad`s (and `IO` is one of them).

There are some other examples of such contexts, which you can use with `do` and `<-`, such as lists, optional, or nullable, values (such as `Maybe Int`), stateful computations and so on.

Some links:

- [What is a monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad)
- http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#do-notation (you need to understand functors and monads here)

Comment: To add to @Yuri's answer, `x <- foo` gets translated to `foo >>= \x -> ...`. As simple as that.

Comment: @arrowd, I thought that that's too into monads, so I told it is just a syntax sugar, and the second link explains the desugaring to `>>=`

Comment: @arrowd "... and `(>>=)` does in fact have a type, which is ..." etc.