# Haskell difference between function composition and bind

Tags: haskell, bind, composition

I can't understand the difference between Dot (function composition) and bind (>>=) .

If I understand, these two ways take the previous result of a function for a new function.

So what is the difference ?

Comment: `(.)` is an operator which works with function types whereas `(>>=)` is an overloaded operator. It works with all types which are instances of Monad type class including the function type `(->) r`. Even with function type they are not exactly the same. However I would advise you to check `fmap` and `(.)` first.

Comment: Roughly put, `(.)` composes `a -> b` and `b -> c`, while `>>=` sort-of _applies_ `M b` to `b -> M c`. Types are completely different, especially because of the monad `M`.

Comment: On the other hand `(.)` and `(<=<)` ("kleisli composition") are quite similar and the difference/analogy between them is worth thinking about

Comment: @luqui indeed, and the `Category` class unifies this general concept of "things that can be composed". (And `Arrow` and its subclasses take it further.) (Note I'm mentioning these in case the OP is interested, not because I think you're unaware of them :-) )

Answer (score 5):

They are pretty different. Let's look at their signatures:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
(>>=) :: (Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

As you said, the function composition is just a way to pass a result of one function as an argument to another one like this:

```
f = g . h
```

is equivalent to

```
f x = g (h x)
```

You can think about is as some kind of a "conveyor", where your value goes through several processing steps.

But `(>>=)` is quite different. It is related to such context as [monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad) which is something like some value in some context (it's highly recommended to read the previous link if you aren't familiar with it).

So let `x` be some value in a context. Our context will be nullability ([`Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html) monad), and the value is `2`. So, `x = Just 2`. We could, for example, get it as a result of a lookup from some associative container (such operation might fail, that's the reason why it is `Maybe Int`, but not `Int`).

Now we want to pass our `x` to some arithmetic function `f` that accepts just `Int` and may fail, so its signature looks like:

```
f :: Int -> Maybe Int
```

We can't just pass our value because of type mismatch. We could unpack `x` and handle some cases with `if`, but we could do that in almost all other languages. In haskell, we can use `(>>=)`:

```
x >>= f
```

This allows as to chain the effects:

- if `x` is `Nothing`, then the result is `Nothing` immediately
- else `x` is unpacked and passed to `f`

This is a generalization of the [operator `?.`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls), that you could see in some languages:

```
x = a?.func1()?.func2();
```

which checks for `null` at each "step" and stops immediately if hits `null` or returns the value in case of success. In haskell it looks like:

```
x = a >>= func1 >>= func2
```

However, bind with monads is a much more powerful concept, allowing you, for example, to emulate stateful computations in a language without mutability like haskell.

Comment: Bind with monads is a much more powerful concept, allowing you, for example, to implement backtracking, coroutines, continuations, exceptions, undoable actions, transactional memory.  Mutable state is the most boring example ever.

Comment: @luqui Whoa. I'm not so experienced in Haskell, so didn't know that monads are that powerful.

Answer (score 4):

`(>>=)` is a form of function *application*.

```
(>>=)          :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
flip ($)       ::              a -> (a ->   b) ->   b
```

It takes a value, but "extracts" part of it in order to apply the given function. Chaining two functions, like `x >>= f >>= g` requires the argument type of `g` to be *different* from (but at the same type *similar* to) the return type of `f`, unlike composition, which requires the types to match *exactly*.

Composed with `return`, it
really *is* just function application, but restricted to certain kinds of functions.

```
flip ($)       ::              a -> (a ->   b) ->   b
(>>=) . return :: Monad m =>   a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

`(.)` is more like `(<=<)` (from `Control.Monad`).

```
(.)   ::            (b ->   c) -> (a ->   b) -> a ->   c
(<=<) :: Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m c
```

But again, instead of simply passing the result of one function to another, it first "extracts" a value before doing application.