# Understanding pure functions and side effects in Haskell - putStrLn

Tags: haskell

Recently, I started learning Haskell because I wanted to broaden my knowledge on functional programming and I must say I am really loving it so far. The resource I am currently using is the course 'Haskell Fundamentals Part 1' on Pluralsight. Unfortunately I have some difficulty understanding one particular quote of the lecturer about the following code and was hoping you guys could shed some light on the topic.

**Accompanying Code**

```
helloWorld :: IO ()
helloWorld = putStrLn "Hello World"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    helloWorld
    helloWorld
    helloWorld
```

**The Quote**

*If you have the same IO action multiple times in a do-block, it will be run multiple times. So this program prints out the string 'Hello World' three times. This example helps illustrate that `putStrLn` is not a function with side effects. We call the `putStrLn` function once to define the `helloWorld` variable. If `putStrLn` had a side effect of printing the string, it would only print once and the `helloWorld` variable repeated in the main do-block wouldn't have any effect.*

*In most other programming languages, a program like this would print 'Hello World' only once, since the printing would happen when the `putStrLn` function was called. This subtle distinction would often trip up beginners, so think about this a bit, and make sure you understand why this program prints 'Hello World' three times and why it would print it only once if the `putStrLn` function did the printing as a side effect.*

**What I don't understand**

For me it seems almost natural that the string 'Hello World' is printed three times. I perceive the `helloWorld` variable (or function?) as a sort of callback which is invoked later. What I don't understand is, how if `putStrLn` had a side effect, it would result in the string being printed only once. Or why it would only be printed once in other programming languages.

Let's say in C# code, I would presume it would look like this:

**C#** [(Fiddle)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1Tl4h2)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void HelloWorld()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        HelloWorld();
        HelloWorld();
        HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

I am sure I am overlooking something quite simple or misinterpret his terminology. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Thank you all for your answers! Your answers helped me get a better understanding of these concepts. I don't think it fully clicked yet, but I will revisit the topic in the future, thank you!

Comment: Think of `helloWorld` being constant such as a field or variable in C#. There's no parameter that is being applied to `helloWorld`.

Comment: `putStrLn` *doesn't* have a side effect; it simply returns an IO action, the *same* IO action for the argument `"Hello World"` no matter how many times you call `putStrLn`.

Comment: If it did, `helloworld` wouldn't be an action that prints `Hello world`; it would be the value returned by `putStrLn` *after* *it* printed `Hello World` (namely, `()`).

Comment: I think to understand this example you would already have to understand how side effects work in Haskell. It's not a good example.

Comment: In your C# snippet you don't do like `helloWorld = Console.WriteLine("Hello World");`. You just contain the `Console.WriteLine("Hello World");` in the `HelloWorld` function to be executed everytime `HelloWorld` is invoked. Now think about what `helloWorld = putStrLn "Hello World"` makes `helloWorld`. It gets assigned to an IO monad which contains `()`. Once you bind it by `>>=` it will only then perform it's activity (printing something) and will give you `()` on the right side of the bind operator.

Comment: the reason it confuses you is that it gives a C-like reading to the Haskell code. `hi = putStrLn("Hi!")` *in C* would print `"Hi!"` and return some value, to be stored in the `hi` variable. In Haskell though that line is not a function call, but a *definition*. It's good that it seems natural to you that it prints three times -- it means you're a *natural* Haskeller!  :) (or FP programmer, in general)

Comment: Philip Wadler provides a smaller example and explanation in section 2.2 of [How to Declare an Imperative](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.3579&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (pages 4-5).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It’d probably be easier to understand what the author means if we define `helloWorld` as a local variable:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let helloWorld = putStrLn "Hello World!"
  helloWorld
  helloWorld
  helloWorld
```

which you could compare to this C#-like pseudocode:

```
void Main() {
  var helloWorld = {
    WriteLine("Hello World!")
  }
  helloWorld;
  helloWorld;
  helloWorld;
}
```

I.e. in C# `WriteLine` is a procedure that prints its argument and returns nothing. In Haskell, `putStrLn` is a function that takes a string and gives you an action that would print that string were it to be executed. It means that there is absolutely no difference between writing

```
do
  let hello = putStrLn "Hello World"
  hello
  hello
```

and

```
do
  putStrLn "Hello World"
  putStrLn "Hello World"
```

That being said, in this example the difference isn’t particularly profound, so it’s fine if you don’t quite get what the author is trying to get at in this section and just move on for now.

it works a bit better if you compare it to python

```
hello_world = print('hello world')
hello_world
hello_world
hello_world
```

The point here being that IO actions in Haskell are “real” values that don’t need to be wrapped in further “callbacks” or anything of the sort to prevent them from executing - rather, the only way to *do* get them to execute is to put them in a particular place (i.e. somewhere inside `main` or a thread spawned off `main`).

This isn’t just a parlour trick either, this does end up having some interesting effects on how you write code (for example, it’s part of the reason why Haskell doesn’t really need any of the common control structures you’d be familiar with from imperative languages and can get away with doing everything in terms of functions instead), but again I wouldn’t worry too much about this (analogies like these don’t always immediately click)

Answer (score 5):

It might be easier to see the difference as described if you use a function that actually does something, rather than `helloWorld`. Think of the following:

```hs
add :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
add x y = do
  putStrLn ("I am adding " ++ show x ++ " and " ++ show y)
  return (x + y)

plus23 :: IO Int
plus23 = add 2 3

main :: IO ()
main = do
  _ <- plus23
  _ <- plus23
  _ <- plus23
  return ()
```

This will print out "I am adding 2 and 3" 3 times.

In C#, you might write the following:

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static int add(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am adding {0} and {1}", x, y);
        return x + y;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int x;
        int plus23 = add(2, 3);
        x = plus23;
        x = plus23;
        x = plus23;
        return;
    }
}
```

Which would print only once.

Answer (score 3):

If the evaluation of `putStrLn "Hello World"` had side effects, then then message would only be printed once.

We can approximate that scenario with the following code:

```
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)
import Control.Exception (evaluate)

helloWorld :: ()
helloWorld = unsafePerformIO $ putStrLn "Hello World"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    evaluate helloWorld
    evaluate helloWorld
    evaluate helloWorld
```

[`unsafePerformIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO) takes an `IO` action and "forgets" it's an `IO` action, unmooring it from the usual sequencing imposed by the composition of `IO` actions and letting the effect take place (or not) according to the vagaries of lazy evaluation.

[`evaluate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:evaluate) takes a pure value and ensures that the value is evaluated whenever the resulting `IO` action is evaluated—which for us it will be, because it lies in the path of `main`. We are using it here to connect the evaluation of some values to the exection of the program.

This code only prints "Hello World" one time. We treat `helloWorld` as a pure value. But that means it will be shared between all `evaluate helloWorld` calls. And why not? It's a pure value after all, why recalculate it needlessly? The first `evaluate` action "pops" the "hidden" effect and the later actions just evaluate the resulting `()`, which doesn't cause any further effects.

Comment: It's worth noting that you should absolutely not be using `unsafePerformIO` at this stage of learning Haskell. It has "unsafe" in the name for a reason, and you shouldn't be using it unless you can (and did) carefully consider the implications of its usage in context. The code that danidiaz put in the answer perfectly captures the sort of unintuitive behavior that can result from `unsafePerformIO`.

Answer (score 1):

There is one detail to notice: you call `putStrLn` function only once, while defining `helloWorld`. In `main` function you just use the return value of that `putStrLn "Hello, World"` three times.

The lecturer says that `putStrLn` call has no side effects and it's true. But look at the type of `helloWorld` - it is an IO action. `putStrLn` just creates it for you. Later, you chain 3 of them with the `do` block to create another IO action - `main`. Later, when you execute your program, that action will be run, that's where side effects lie.

The mechanism that lies in base of this - [monads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad). This powerful concept allows you to use some side effects like printing in a language that doesn't support side effects directly. You just chain some actions, and that chain will be run on start of your program. You will need to understand that concept deeply if you want to use Haskell seriously.