# Retrieving value wrapped in IO

Tags: scala, io, monads, scala-cats

Is there a way to get the value inside an `IO`, without using `unsafeRunSync()` ?

For instance, I have a

```
val x : IO[Long] = IO$9125
```

I want to get the Long value in order to perform some computation on it without using `unsafeRunSync()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't want to get the value from [monadic](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monad.html) context. This is incorrect way of thinking (retrieving the value from a context is typical for [`Comonad`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/comonad.html)).

[Monads in pictures.](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html)

[What is a monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad)

You shouldn't want to get `A` from `Option[A]`, `A` from `List[A]`, `A` from `Future[A]`, `A` from `IO[A]`... As soon as you get into monadic calculation you should continue to work inside the monad, with `.map`, `.flatMap`, `for`-comprehensions etc.

For example for `val x: IO[Long] = ...`  inside

```
for {
  long <- x
  ...
} yield ...
```

`long` has type `Long`.

So you do calculations inside `IO` and execute `unsafeRunSync()` or `unsafePerformIO()` once at the very end.

Answer (score 4):

Because `IO` forms a `Functor` you can map over it

```
IO(41L).map(_ + 1)
```

Because `IO` forms a `Monad` you can put it through a for-comprehension

```
for {
  a <- IO(1L)
  b <- IO(41L)
} yield a + b
```

Note that semantics of `IO` do not really mean it is a kind of *container* that holds a value which we can take out of the container. Instead it captures the idea of executing a side-effect as separate from evaluating business logic.