# Monads - Definition, Laws and Example

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad)

I am learning to program in the functional language of Haskell and I came across **Monads** when studying parsers. I had never heard of them before and so I did some extra studying to find out what they are.

Everywhere I look in order to learn this topic just confuses me. I can't really find a simple definition of what a Monad is and how to use them. "A monad is a way to structure computations in terms of values and sequences of computations using those values" - eh???

Can someone please provide a simple definition of what a Monad is in Haskell, the laws associated with them and give an example?

- Note: I know how to use the do syntax as I have had a look at I/O actions and functions with side-effects.

Comment: There are tons of good tutorials out there. An example would be http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads, maybe you should first read the chapter about functors. Also, please list the resources you already read and didn't understand

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704652/monad-in-plain-english-for-the-oop-programmer-with-no-fp-background/2704795#2704795

Comment: The following is my personal humble opinion. You really, truly need to understand deeply what a monad in the category theory is, including its connection with adjoints. Most Haskell-oriented tutorials barely touch this, which makes them rather confusing and pointless. Sorry, programming is complicated, no way around this.

Comment: @n.m.: I agree. However, it helps to have a basic understanding of how monads are used in programming before diving into the category-theoretical details

Comment: The problem with understanding monads is that they are a very general and abstract concept. See [Differenv ways to see a monad](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/161443/different-ways-to-see-a-monad/161464#161464) where I tried to explain it.

Comment: @n.m. You need to deeply understand monads at the category theoretic level *to do what*? If you want to do new research in programming languages, I agree. If you want to write concise programs using monads to structure your computations, I emphatically do not agree.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: to understand what you are really doing and why. It is much much easier this way. One can use existing monadic libraries without any understanding of CT, no doubt, but it's hard, and creating new ones is much harder.

Comment: @n.m. it's a bit of a tautology to say that "you need to understand deeply what a monad ... is to understand what you are really doing [when you use monads]".  I don't think it helps much when using existing monadic libraries either, unless you mean generic monad-manipulation libraries (e.g. transformers, Control.Monad, stuff like that).  For that, and certainly creating new monads, I agree that it's helpful.

Comment: @n.m. I understand that sort of stuff now. But I learned and understood enough about monads to use them very well and productively in structuring plenty of software, including libraries, before I could ever give a decent definition of an adjunction, a natural transformation, or even a correct, category-theoretic account of a functor. You can also define monads in CT terms in a perfectly useful and clear manner without dealing with adjunctions at all!

Comment: @sclv: well, you can define monads without adjunctions, but it's not helpful. One needs to realize how e.g. the IO monad results from the round trip from the pure-functions category to the computations-with-side-effects category and back. No Haskell-oriented monads tutorial that I know of talks about this stuff.

Answer (score 6):

## Intuition

A rough intuition would be that a Monad is a particular kind of container (`Functor`), for which you have two operations available. A wrapping operation `return` that takes a single element into a container. An operation `join` that merges a container of containers into a single container.

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a     
join   :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

So for the Monad Maybe you have:

```
return :: a -> Maybe a     
return x = Just x

join :: Maybe (Maybe a) -> Maybe a
join (Just (Just x) = Just x
join (Just Nothing) = Nothing 
join Nothing        = Nothing
```

Likewise for the Monad [ ] these operations are defined to be:

```
return :: a -> [a]     
return x = [x]

join :: [[a]] -> [a]
join xs = concat xs
```

The standard mathematical definition of Monad is based on these return and join operators. However in Haskell the definition of the class Monad substitutes a bind operator for join.

## Monads in Haskell

In functional programming languages these special containers are typically used to denote effectful computations. The type `Maybe a` would represent a computation that may or may not succeed, and the type `[a]` a computation that is non-deterministic. Particularly we're interested in functions with effects, i.e.those with types `a->m b` for some `Monad m`. And we need to be able to compose them. This can be done using either a monadic composition or bind operator.

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

In Haskell the latter is the standard one. Note that its type is very similar to the type of the application operator (but with flipped arguments):

```
(>>=)    :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
flip ($) ::              a -> (a ->   b) -> b
```

It takes an effectful function `f :: a -> m b` and a computation `mx :: m a` returning values of type `a`, and performs the application `mx >>= f`. So how do we do this with Monads? Containers (`Functors`) can be mapped, and in this case the result is a computation within a computation which can then be flattened:

```
fmap f mx        :: m (m b)
join (fmap f mx) :: m b
```

So we have:

```
(mx >>= f) = join (fmap f mx) :: m b
```

To see this working in practise consider a simple example with lists (non-deterministic functions). Suppose you have a list of possible results `mx = [1,2,3]` and a non-deterministic function `f x = [x-1, x*2]`. To calculate `mx >>= f` you begin by mapping mx with f and then you merge the results::

```
fmap f mx                = [[0,2],[1,4],[2,6]]    
join [[0,2],[1,4],[2,6]] = [0,2,1,4,2,6]
```

Since in Haskell the bind operator `(>>=)` is more important than `join`, for efficiency reasons in the latter is defined from the former and not the other way around.

```
join mx = mx >>= id
```

Also the bind operator, being defined with join and fmap, can also be used to define a mapping operation. For this reason Monads are not required to be instances of the class Functor. The equivalent operation to fmap is called `liftM` in the Monad library.

```
liftM f mx = mx >>= \x-> return (f x)
```

So the actual definitions for the Monads Maybe becomes:

```
return :: a -> Maybe a     
return x = Just x

(>>=)    :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
Nothing >>= f = Nothing 
Just x  >>= f = f x
```

And for the Monad [ ]:

```
return :: a -> [a]     
return x = [x]

(>>=)    :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
         = concatMap f xs    -- same as above but more efficient
```

When designing your own Monads you may find it easier to, instead of trying to directly define `(>>=)`, split the problem in parts and figure out what how to map and join your structures. Having map and join can also be useful to verify that your Monad is well defined, in the sense that it satisfy the required laws.

## Monad Laws

Your Monad should be a Functor, so the mapping operation should satisfy:

```
fmap id = id
fmap g . fmap f = fmap (g . f)
```

The laws for return and join are:

```
join . return      = id
join . fmap return = id  
join . join = join . fmap join
```

The first two laws specify that merging undoes wrapping. If you wrap a container in another one, join gives you back the original. If you map the contents of a container with a wrapping operation, join again gives you back what you initially had. The last law is the associativity of join. If you have three layers of containers you get the same result by merging from the inside or the outside.

Again you can work with bind instead of join and fmap. You get fewer but (arguably) more complicated laws:

```
return a >>= f  = f a
m >>= return    = m
(m >>= f) >>= g = m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
```

Comment: I think this answer gets to little love... the `join` based laws made my day, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

A monad in Haskell is something that has two operations defined:

```
(>>=)  :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b -- also called bind
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

These two operations need to satisfy certain laws that really might just confuse you at this point, if you don't have a knack for mathy ideas. Conceptually, you use bind to operate on values on a monadic level and return to create monadic values from "trivial" ones. For instance,

`getLine :: IO String`,

so you cannot modify and `putStrLn` this `String` -- because it's not a `String` but an `IO String`!

Well, we have an IO Monad handy, so not to worry. All we have to do is use bind to do what we want. Let's see what bind looks like in the IO Monad:

```
(>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
```

And if we place `getLine` at the left hand side of bind, we can make it more specific yet.

```
(>>=) :: IO String -> (String -> IO b) -> IO b
```

Okay, so `getLine >>= putStrLn . (++ ". No problem after all!")` would print the entered line with the extra content added. The right hand side is a function that takes a `String` and produces an `IO ()` - that wasn't hard at all! We just go by the types.

There are Monads defined for a lot of different types, for instance `Maybe` and `[a]`, and they behave conceptually in the same way.

`Just 2 >>= return . (+2)` would yield `Just 4`, as you might expect. Note that we had to use `return` here, because otherwise the function on the right hand side would **not** match the return type `m b`, but just `b`, which would be a type error. It worked in the case of putStrLn because it already produces an `IO` something, which was exactly what our type needed to match. (Spoiler: Expressions of shape `foo >>= return . bar` are silly, because every `Monad` is a `Functor`. Can you figure out what that means?)

I personally think that this is as far as intuition will get you on the topic of monads, and if you want to dive deeper, you really do need to dive into the theory. I liked getting a hang of just using them first. You can look up the source for various Monad instances, for instance the List (`[]`) Monad or `Maybe` Monad on Hoogle and get a bit smarter on the exact implementations. Once you feel comfortable with that, have a go at the actual monad laws and try to gain a more theoretical understanding for them!

Comment: I would like to add, as an aside, that this does **not** count as a Monad tutorial, so I am still at an all time zero when it comes to personal Monad tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

The [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia) has a section about [`Monad`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Monad) (but do read the preceding sections about [`Functor`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Functor) and [`Applicative`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Applicative) first).