# ProjectEuler solution returns incorrect answer

Tags: java, math

The problem I'm trying to solve comes from ProjectEuler.

Some integers have following property:

```
n + reverse(n) = a number consisting entirely of odd digits.
```

For example:

```
14: 14 + 41 = 55
```

Numbers starting or ending with 0 aren't allowed.

How many of these "reversible" numbers are there below `10^9`?

The problem also gives a hint:

> there are 120 such numbers below 1000.

I'm quite new to Java, and I tried to solve this problem by writing a program that checks all the numbers up to a billion, which is not the best way, I know, but I'm ok with that.

The problem is that my program gives out a wrong amount of numbers and I couldn't figure out why! (The code will most likely contain some ugly things, feel free to improve it in any way)

```
int result = 0;
boolean isOdd = true;
boolean hasNo0 = true;

public int reverseNumber(int r)    //this method should be working 
{                          //guess the main problem is in the second method
    int n = 0;
    String m = "";
    if (r % 10 == 0) { hasNo0 = false; }
    while (r > 0){
    n = r % 10;
    m = String.valueOf(m+n);    
    r /= 10;                       
    }
    result = Integer.parseInt(m);  
    return result;
}

public void isSumOdd(int max)
{
    int number = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    Sums reverseIt = new Sums();
    int amount = 0;

    while (number <= max)
    {
        sum = reverseIt.reverseNumber(number) + number;
        while (sum > 0)
        {
            int x = sum % 10;
            if (x % 2 == 0) { isOdd = false; }
            sum /= 10;
        }
        if (isOdd && hasNo0) { amount++; }
        number++;
        isOdd = true;
        hasNo0 = true;
    }
    System.out.println(amount);
}
```

Called by

```
Sums first = new Sums();
first.reversibleNumbers(1000000000);
```

Comment: Did you try to find out why it is not working? How?

Comment: The program prints `125` as a result if you run it for the first `1000` numbers.

Comment: @miserableVariable yes, I've tried to understand what was wrong but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important problem in your code is the following line:

> sum = reverseIt.reverseNumber(number) + number;

in `isSumOdd(int max)` function. Here the `reverseIt` object is a new instance of `Sums` class. Since you are using `Sums` member data (the `boolean` variables) to signal some conditions when you use the new instance the value of these member variables is not copied to the current caller object. You have to change the line to:

> sum = this.reverseNumber(number) + number;

and remove the `Sums reverseIt = new Sums();` declaration and initialization.

**Edit:** Attempt to explain why there is no need to instantiate new object instance to call a method - I've found the following answer which explains the difference between a `function` and a `(object)method`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/155655/25429. IMO the explanation should be enough (you don't need a new object because the member method *already* has access to the member data in the object).

Comment: Although other answers presents options to simplify the code this is the right answer. Could you elaborate to @feflopizer why he does not have to instanciate a new Object to access a method from the same object. In my opinion this is the root cause of his problems.

Comment: @ViniciusZaramella - I've added some text.

Comment: @zloster Thank you very much, everything is much clearer now!

Comment: @feflopizer If my answer helped you it will be nice to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite odd check for given digit when checking the next one with this code: `isOdd = false;`. So in the outcome you check only whether the first digit is odd.
You should replace this line with

```
idOdd = idOdd && (x % 2 == 0);
```

BTW. You should be able to track down an error like this easily with simple unit tests, the practice I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key problems here is that your `reverseNumber` method does two things: check if the number has a zero *and* reverses the number. I understand that you want to ignore the result (or really, you have no result) if the number is a multiple of 10. Therefore, you have two approaches:

1. Only send numbers into `reverseNumber` if they are not a multiple of 10. This is called a precondition of the method, and is probably the easiest solution.
2. Have a way for your method to give back no result. This is a popular technique in an area of programming called ["Functional Programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), and is usually implemented with a tool called a [Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2704795/1473653). In Java, these are implemented with the `Optional<>` class. These allow your method (which always has to return *something*) to return an object that means "nothing at all". These will allow you to know if your method was unable or unwilling to give you a result for some reason (in this case, the number had a zero in it).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick working snippet:

```
class Prgm
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int max=(int)Math.pow(10, 3);    //change it to (10, 9) for 10^9
        for(int i=1;i<=max;i++)
        {
            if(i%10==0)
                continue;
            String num=Integer.toString(i);
            String reverseNum=new StringBuffer(num).reverse().toString();
            String sum=(new Long(i+Long.parseLong(reverseNum))).toString();
            if(sum.matches("^[13579]+$"))
                System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

It prints 1 number(satisfying the condition) per line, `wc` is `word count` linux program used here to count number of lines

```
$javac Prgm.java  
$java Prgm
...//Prgm outputs numbers  1 per line
$java Prgm | wc --lines
120
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that separating functionnalities will transform the problem to be easier. Here is a solution for your problem. Perhaps it isn't the best but that gives a good result:

```
public static void main(final String [] args)    {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        final int reversNumber = reverseNumber(i);
        final int sum = i + reversNumber;
        if (hasNoZeros(i) && isOdd(sum)) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println("i: " + i);
            System.out.println("r: " + reversNumber);
            System.out.println("s: " + sum);


        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);

}

public static boolean hasNoZeros(final int i){
    final String s = String.valueOf(i);
    if (s.startsWith("0") || s.endsWith("0")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static int reverseNumber(final int i){
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(i));
    return Integer.parseInt(sb.reverse().toString());
}


public static boolean isOdd(final int i){
    for (final char s : String.valueOf(i).toCharArray()) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s))%2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;

}
```

the output is:

`i: 12
r: 21
s: 33
i: 14
r: 41
s: 55
i: 16
r: 61
s: 77
i: 18
r: 81
s: 99
4`