# Disambiguation of higher kinded type vs higher order type

Tags: type-systems, higher-kinded-types, higher-order-types

In a previous question I asked [Why can the Monad interface not be declared in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951818/why-can-the-monad-interface-not-be-declared-in-java). There, I received a comment from Brian Goetz saying that I should have called "higher order types" "higher *kinded* types".

Now, I read more about type systems and I understand the concept of higher kinded types. However, I am still confused by the terms. I tried to disambiguate them by myself using Google, however there does not seem to be a clear answer. Thus, my question is what is the exact meaning of the following terms:

- higher order type
- higher kinded type
- higher order kind

Do all three terms exist? Is there a difference between them? What is the difference? Does the meaning vary between programming languages?

I also noticed that StackOverflow has multiple tags:

- [higher-order-types](/questions/tagged/higher-order-types)
- [higher-kinded-types](/questions/tagged/higher-kinded-types)

However, there is no tag wiki for both of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [this](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/115/higher-rank-and-higher-kinded-types) blog post, the term *higher order type* seems to be the common term for *higher kinded type* and *higher rank type*. *higher order kind* is probably a term that I just made up when I was confused.

#### Higher kinded type

With higher kinded types, it is possible to receive a type parameter that itself is a generic type:

```
interface Foo<T<_>> {
    T<String> get();
}
```

This is what is necessary to declare the `Monad` interface.

#### Higher rank type

With higher rank types, it is possible to receive a parameter whose type still contains unspecified type parameters:

```
interface Bar {
    void foobar(<E> List<E> list);
}
```

Unfortunately, higher rank type checking/inference is undecidable.

Comment: It depends. Actually, rank-2 types are decidable, although not trivially. Anything higher is undecidable to my knowledge.