# Understanding Monad

Tags: monads

## Question

Please help confirm or correct the understandings of what Monad is and its traits.

#### As Data Type

In my understanding, a Monad is:

1. a container which can accommodate any type T and
2. provides a **bind** interface that allows its client to apply a flat-map function and
3. projects its content into another Monad of any type T'.

There need to be a **return** or **unit** interface to create a Monad of type T.

```
unit:= T -> M[T]
```

[image]

In Scala, List() or Set() are the examples of **return** interface, and any Scala sequence types (Array, List, Map, String) are Monad which provide **flatMap** interface which is **bind**.

Are these correct?

#### As Design Pattern

Software engineering provides ways to manage complexity or to structure software, such as Structured Programming without goto, UNIX pipe to pipeline transformation, Object Oriented to encapsulate data & control access, etc.

Is Monad a design pattern providing a way to structure a computation as a chain?

## In other systems

#### UNIX commands

I suppose UNIX commands e.g. cat, grep are functions that can be chained but it does not mean they are Monad, and they are not Monad because they do not have **return/unit** nor they are not data type. Or is it still regarded e.g. IO Monad as in [Monadic i/o and UNIX shell programming](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/monadic-shell.html)?

#### Python

I believe there is no **bind** or Scala flatMap equivalent in Python out of the box. Can I say Python does not have Monad feature out of the box?

## References

- [Demystifying the Monad in Scala](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/demystifying-the-monad-in-scala-cc716bb6f534)
- [Functors, Applicatives, And Monads In Pictures](https://github.com/dbrattli/OSlash/wiki/Functors,-Applicatives,-And-Monads-In-Pictures)
- [Functional Programming and Category Theory [Part 1] - Categories and Functors](https://nikgrozev.com/2016/03/14/functional-programming-and-category-theory-part-1-categories-and-functors/)
- [Monad (functional programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming))
- [Monad in plain English? (For the OOP programmer with no FP background)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704652/monad-in-plain-english-for-the-oop-programmer-with-no-fp-background/2704795)

Comment: no (to your graphic), `bind` applies `f (A -> M[B])` to `A` value(s) "in" the `M[A]` value and produces one combined `M[B]` value. if we just `map` that `f` we end up with `M[M[B]]`, but monadic bind "splices" those `M[B]`s inside the one combined `M[B]`: `twice_each [x,y,z] = [x,x] ++ [y,y] ++ [z,z]` or `twice_each xs: for x in xs: for a in [x,x]: yield a`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you're right about those interface things. However, it is noteworthy that in abstraction, a monad should have two adjunctive methods which can be composed to chain the computations. Note that flatMap is simply the composition of such methods - flat and map. map can be used to define a computation of type M[A] -> M[M[B]] and flat which is used to define M[M[B]] -> M[B].
2. Yes, in Scala they're a means to chain computations.
3. The shell script commands may fulfil the purpose of the monads (in the considered analogies) but still can't be regarded as monads (by me at least) as they don't necessarily comply with point 1.
4. Yes, the monads are NOT supported out-of-the-box in Python. One has to rely on the nested loops only.