# How to access a property that only exists on one of my two return types?

Tags: typescript

I have a function being called:

```
const accountDetails: IAccount | ISmallError = getAccount()
```

It might return IAccount or ISmallError.

On the next line I want to do this:

```
if (accountDetails.error) return response.json({ error: error.error });
```

But under `.error` it says

```
Property 'error' does not exist on type 'IAccount | ISmallError'.
  Property 'error' does not exist on type 'IAccount'.ts(2339)
```

what do I do about this?

One solution that does work is:

```
const err = accountDetails as ISmallError;
if (err.error) return response.json({ accountDetails: "No account found" });
```

but is this *the best* way?

Comment: A better way would be to type-narrow between `IAccount` and `ISmallError` in the JavaScript logic - depends on how those two types are typed.

Comment: You can narrow the union type using the `in` operator (e.g. `if ('error' in err) {/*...*/}`) or — instead — use a [monadic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2704652/438273) return type such as [`Result<OkType, ErrorType>`](https://github.com/sniptt-official/monads/tree/v0.5.10/lib/result#introduction) (e.g. `Result<IAccount, ISmallError>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the property is meant to be a discriminant property something as simple as `'error' in accountDetails` will be sufficient:

```js
type IAccount = { payload: 2 }
type ISmallError = { error: Error }
declare const getAccount: () => IAccount | ISmallError;

const accountDetails: IAccount | ISmallError = getAccount()

if ('error' in accountDetails) {
  accountDetails.error // No longer an error
}
```

Using a property existence check is *better* (in my opinion) because it uses the type system instead of overriding it (as the cast does), ensuring we will get an error in more circumstances in future.

Even *better* would be to introduce a proper discriminant property to  `IAccount` and `ISmallError` so that you can switch on the tag.  That helps avoid the case where `IAccount` grows its *own* `error` field in the future (fewer places for collisions makes for an easier-to-maintain codebase):

```js
type IAccount = { type: 'accountDetails', payload: 2 }
type ISmallError = { type: 'prodError', error: Error }

// ... snip ...

if (accountDetails.type === 'prodError') {
  // Full narrowing here and no potential overlapping fields later
}
```