# Maybe/Option monad in C#

Tags: c#, option-type, monads

It's 2015, is there any "official" maybe monad in C#? Ideally, it would work something ala Scala's Option, Some and None types.

C# seems to have everything needed, i.e. co/contravariance and lambdas.

I'm asking this because I recently started working in a company that uses Unity, and I run into a lot of delayed initialization. In an attempt to avoid NullPointerException, I would like to maybe invite them into the monad world. Any ideas on this, or should we simply deal with this in another way?

Comment: No, there are no official monads "out of the box", but you can find many implementations on Nuget

Comment: Check this out: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/monads-in-c-5-maybe.html. Thought I seriously doubt whether this increases readability. I would go for Java's Optional construct instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674855/help-a-c-sharp-developer-understand-what-is-a-monad The accepted answer also links to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2008/01/11/the-marvels-of-monads.aspx

Comment: Ignoring (at my peril) your specific request for monad, for "a lot of delayed initialization", any chance you just need to use the `Lazy<T>` class? Your question is missing a lot of context that would help people understand what specific _problem_ you're actually trying to solve. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, as well as http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Of course there is such a type - it hides in `FSharp.Core` ;)

Comment: I think you may need to look into how your new company actually handles this delayed initialization currently and see how their current approach works for them

Comment: Dennis_E> The "monadsinc5" one is great. I think SelectMany and GetEnumerator are what I need to use a maybe-like monad effectively. In the end, what I needed was just a way to push the possibility of a null-value into the type system and a way to manipulate them without checking for null all the time.

Comment: This is my implementation: https://github.com/gsscoder/csharpx.

Answer (score 1):

As far as "official" approaches go, remember that if you're using C# 6, you can use the [null-conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx):

```
var myVal = possiblyNull?.thisToo?.andThis?.value;
```

Certain VisualStudio templates (such as the ASP.NET MVC project template) also include the [`IsNotNull` extension method](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AjaxMinDll/Extensions.cs), which is part of the AjaxMinExtensions. If you don't have those in your project, you could copy/paste the implementation into your code.

```
var myVal = possiblyNull.IfNotNull(v => v.doTheThing())
                        .IfNotNull(theThing => theThing.TheProperty);
```

Comment: while beeing called a "monadic" operator that is not quite the same - if you go with a `Maybe<T>` or `Option<T>` type the compiler will help you see the places where you missed handling possible null values (by giving you errors)

Comment: @CarstenKönig Yes, certainly true.