# What is exactly an indexed functor in Haskell and what are its usages?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor, category-theory

When studying functors in Haskell I came up with [Functor.Indexed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras-0.53.4/docs/Control-Functor-Indexed.html) type of functor. This functor defines an operation called `imap`. I didn't understood its definition and `imap` signature: `imap :: (a -> b) -> f j k a -> f j k b`. I tried to find it s formal definition and found only this: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/indexed+functor . But it really didn't help me at all. So can someone clarify in more simple words this kind of functor and in what cases should I use it? Thanks.

Comment: My feeling is that the motivation behind indexed functors can be understood only by looking at indexed _applicative_ functors, or indexed monads. These are just like their non-indexed parts, except that the type (in its index) is allowed to change when using `<*>` or `>>=`. The index can therefore be used e.g. to keep track of how many side effects you have: `allocSomeData :: M Zero One T1` and `allocSomeOtherData :: M One Two T2` then `do d1 <- allocSomeData; d2 <- allocSomeOtherData; return (d1,d2) :: M Zero Two (T1,T2)` and the double allocation is reflected in the type.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An indexed functor is, to use [spacesuitburritoesque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261729/monad-in-non-programming-terms) wording, “a container that also contains a mapping”. I.e. a value `f j k a` will “contain” some sort of morphism(s) `j -> k` <sup>(not necessarily functions, can be more general arrows)</sup> and also values of type `a`.

For those `a` values, the container is a functor in the obvious way. In fact the `IxFunctor` class on its own is pretty boring – an

```
instance IxFunctor f
```

is basically the same as

```
instance Functor (f j k)
```

Now, where it gets interesting is when you consider the more specific functor classes. This monad one isn't actually in the `Indexed` module, but I think it makes the point best clear:

```
class IxPointed f => IxMonad f where
  ijoin :: m j k (m k l a) -> m j l a
```

compare this side-by-side:

```
(>>>) ::  (j->k) -> (k->l)   ->   j->l
ijoin :: m j  k   (m k  l a) -> m j  l a
join  :: m        (m      a) -> m      a
```

So what we do is, while joining the “container-layers”, we *compose* the morphisms.

The obvious example is `IxState`. Recall the standard state monad

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

This, when used as a monad, simply composes the `s -> s` aspect of the function:

```
  join (State f) = State $ \s -> let (State f', s') = f s in f' s'
```

so you thread the state first through `f`, then through `f'`. Well, there's really no reason we need all the states to have the same type, right? After all, the intermediate state is merely passed on to the next action. Here's the indexed state monad,

```
newtype IxState i j a = IxState { runIxState :: i -> (a, j) }
```

It does just that:

```
  ijoin (IxState f) = IxState $ \s -> let (IxState f', s') = f s in f' s'
```

Comment: If I've understood that correctly, it should be `runIxState :: i -> (a, j)`, shouldn't it? And thanks for this really good explanation, now these finally make sense for me...

Comment: Great notion of 'simultaneously composes morphisms'