# Context in data instances

Tags: haskell, type-constraints, gadt

I have a datatype which only makes sense if its arguments can be ordered, however I seem to be needing to get deep into some complex and potentially hacky stuff to get it to work (GADTs, mainly).
Is what I'm doing (constrained datatypes) considered bad haskell practice, and is there any way around this?

For those interested, here's the relevant code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
import Data.List (sort)

data OrdTriple a where
    OrdTriple :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> a -> OrdTriple a

instance Functor OrdTriple where
    fmap :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> OrdTriple a -> OrdTriple b
    fmap f (OrdTriple n d x) = OrdTriple n' d' x'
        where 
            [n', d', x'] = sort [f n, f d, f x]
```

At first I thought I'd just put a context in the Functor instance (it's the only instance I'm struggling with) but it seems I can't (no mention of the contained type), and even if I could I'd still need the constraint on `fmap` that its return type be orderable.

As it is, I'm getting the following compile error, which it seems is because I'm overly constraining the Functor instance:

```
No instance for (Ord a)
Possible fix:
  add (Ord a) to the context of
    the type signature for
      fmap :: (a -> b) -> OrdTriple a -> OrdTriple b
When checking that:
    forall a b.
    (Ord a, Ord b) =>
    (a -> b) -> OrdTriple a -> OrdTriple b
  is more polymorphic than:
    forall a b. (a -> b) -> OrdTriple a -> OrdTriple b
When checking that instance signature for ‘fmap’
  is more general than its signature in the class
  Instance sig: forall a b.
                (Ord a, Ord b) =>
                (a -> b) -> OrdTriple a -> OrdTriple b
     Class sig: forall a b. (a -> b) -> OrdTriple a -> OrdTriple b
In the instance declaration for ‘Functor OrdTriple’
```

Comment: Functor must be applicable for all types, not just those constrained by `Ord`.  You can't constrain it further even in your instance.  This is why structures like balanced trees can't be functors either.

Comment: You can't make that a functor. The usual way around that is then to simply implement a separate "map" function, as is done for `Data.Set` and `Data.Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this using the standard `Functor` class, since its `fmap` must work on *all* data types, without constraints.

You could work with a different class. One option is to use an "fine-grained functor" class which lets you use a separate instance for each pairs of types `a b`. (Probably this already has some standard name, but I can't remember)

```
class FgFunctor f a b where
   fgmap :: (a->b) -> f a -> f b

-- regular functors are also fine-grained ones, e.g.
instance FgFunctor [] a b where
   fgmap = fmap

instance (Ord a, Ord b) => FgFunctor OrdTriple a b where
   fgmap f (OrdTriple n d x) = OrdTriple n' d' x'
      where [n', d', x'] = sort [f n, f d, f x]
```

Alternatively, one can parametrize the `Functor` class with a constraint:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures, MultiParamTypeClasses, 
    ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}
module CFunctor where

import Data.List (sort)
import Data.Kind (Constraint)

data OrdTriple a where
    OrdTriple :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> a -> OrdTriple a

class CFunctor (f :: * -> *) where
   type C f a :: Constraint
   cmap :: (C f a, C f b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

-- regular functors are also constrained ones, e.g.
instance CFunctor [] where
   type C [] a = a ~ a
   cmap = fmap

instance CFunctor OrdTriple where
   type C OrdTriple a = Ord a
   cmap f (OrdTriple n d x) = OrdTriple n' d' x'
      where [n', d', x'] = sort [f n, f d, f x]
```

Comment: Is your IxFunctor related to either [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27771772/6112457) or (slightly different) [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/indexed-0.1.3/docs/Data-Functor-Indexed.html)? I can't tell if they represent similar concepts in some way I'm not seeing, or if they're completely different.

Comment: @ZoeyHewll It seems I messed up the terminology: the one above is not an indexed functor `f i j a`, but something else. I can't remember its proper name, but I would be surprised if this isn't found somewhere. I'll edit away the terminology so not to cause confusion. Thanks.

Comment: For CFunctor, I'm getting `Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Constraint’`

Comment: @ZoeyHewll See my edit, I added the imports and reworked a bit the class, since I also realized we needed a functional dependency or type family. I went for the latter.