# Functor supertype has conflicting instances

Tags: haskell

I have defined a [Fine-Grained Functor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42859793/6112457) class (`FgFunctor`) in order to apply a constraint to the type of functions that may map over my Ordered Triple datatype (`OrdTriple`), which requires the contained type be orderable.

```
import Data.List (sort)

-- 'fine-grained' functor
class FgFunctor f a b where
    fgmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

data OrdTriple a = OrdTriple a a a deriving Show

instance (Ord a, Ord b) => FgFunctor OrdTriple a b where
    fgmap f (OrdTriple n d x) = OrdTriple n' d' x'
        where [n', d', x'] = sort [f n, f d, f x]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let test = fgmap (* 10^4) $ OrdTriple 1 6 11 
    print test
```

The code works fine until I define all other `Functor`s to also be `FgFunctor`s, like so:

```
-- all regular functors are also fine-grained ones
instance Functor f => FgFunctor f a b where
    fgmap = fmap
```

With that instance declaration, as soon as I try to use `fgmap` on my `OrdTriple` type, the compiler complains about overlapping instance declarations

```
Overlapping instances for FgFunctor OrdTriple b0 b0
  arising from a use of ‘fgmap’
Matching instances:
  instance Functor f => FgFunctor f a b
    -- Defined at OrdTriple.hs:15:10
  instance (Ord a, Ord b) => FgFunctor OrdTriple a b
    -- Defined at OrdTriple.hs:18:10
In the expression: fgmap (* 10 ^ 4)
In the expression: fgmap (* 10 ^ 4) $ OrdTriple 1 6 11
In an equation for ‘test’:
    test = fgmap (* 10 ^ 4) $ OrdTriple 1 6 11
```

However, the first 'matching instance' it refers to should never apply to `OrdTriple`, as `OrdTriple` is not a `Functor`, and so I am struggling to determine what is causing the supposed overlap.

Comment: See also related work. The simplest, in a way most hands-on approach is [`MonoFunctor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.2/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFunctor), which does not derive any general instance. Functor classes in generalised/constrained category-theory libraries, like my [`Constrained.Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.3.0.1/docs/Control-Functor-Constrained.html#t:Functor),  solve the problem by giving the prelude-functor derived instance unambiguous tags (the category to work in).

Comment: Is my understanding correct that a `MonoTraversible` type, when mapped over, always returns a `MonoTraversible` of the same type? So `(omap f (xs :: t)) :: t` for all legal combinations of `f` and `x`?

Comment: Yes, that class is indeed quite limiting.

Answer (score 5):

When the compiler (GHC) looks for instances of a type class for a specific type, it doesn't take contexts of each instance into account. That's why it found two instances of `FgFunctor` for `OrdTriple` even though `OrdTriple` is not an instance of `Functor`.

[GHC/AdvancedOverlap](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap) shows you how you can solve this situation.