# Simple Haskell Monad - Random Number

Tags: haskell, random, state, monads, random-seed

I'm trying to extend the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944170/haskell-and-state) (accepted answer) to allow me to be able to call randomGen2 to get a random number, based on the function randomGen which takes a seed as an argument.  But everytime I call randomGen2, despite returning an Int, I get an error about not been able to print Random (when infact I am only trying to print Int).

```
<interactive>:3:1:
    No instance for (Show (Random Int))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (Random Int))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Here's the code:

```
import Control.Monad.State

type Seed = Int

randomGen :: Seed -> (Int, Seed)
randomGen seed = (seed,seed+1)

type Random a = State Seed a

randomGen2 :: Random Int
randomGen2 = do
        seed <- get
        let (x,seed') = randomGen seed
        put seed'
        return x
```

any ideas?

**Update - expected behaviour**
I'm hoping to be able to do something this from an interpreter (e.g. GHCI) -

```
> getRandomInit 1
> -- some other stuff, e.g. 2 + 3
> getRandom
```

i.e. I can set up my getRandom function with a seed, which then stores the seed using `put`, then this function returns and exits.  I then do some other stuff, then call getRandom again, and the seed is retrieved from the Monad where it was stored.

Comment: `getRandomInit` is `System.Random.setStdGen`. Note that `setStdGen` takes `StdGen` not `Int`. You can create one from an `Int` with `mkStdGen`. `getRandom` is `System.Random.randomIO`. Check out the documentation for more details. Also keep in mind that if you want a global state, this has to live inside `IO` - you can't use `State`.

Answer (score 2):

`randomGen2` returns a `Random Int` which is a `State Seed Int` so you'll need to use `runState` to get a result by providing a seed value e.g.

```
runState randomGen2 1
```

If you want to keep repeating the application of `randomGen2` you can create a function like:

```
genRandoms :: Seed -> [Int]
genRandoms s = let (v, s') = runState randomGen2 s in v : genRandoms s'
```

or you could use `sequence`:

```
genRandoms :: Seed -> [Int]
genRandoms s = fst $ runState (sequence (repeat randomGen2)) s
```

Comment: Ok, it now executes, but I'm getting returned (1,2) rather than just 1 (which is odd, since I thought in my code I'm only returning the int X from the group (x,seed'), and it stays the same every time i.e. when I run it twice I get (1,2) both times rather than (1,2), (2,3) (which I should get if the seed is been stored and retrieved)?

Comment: @SamHeather - `runState` returns a pair containing the result and the final state value. If you just want the result you can extract it using `fst` e.g. `fst $ runState randomGen2 1`

Comment: ok, that addresses the first question, but how can I be able to run this again with the adjusted value for the state?  I thought I'd be able to keep executing randomGen2 and get a different random Int every time because the seed changed and was stored?

Comment: @SamHeather - I've updated the answer - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: `fst .: runState` is `evalState`.

Comment: @Lee can I get your opinion on whether this would be the best way for me to get a list of random numbers in Haskell from a seed which I give and manipulate?  Also, this is still not the behaviour I was expecting - I've updated the question to clarify - sorry I wasn't very clear.  Not even sure if this is possible in Haskell and my book doesn't help!